# Make borderpane resize to fit scene

Tags: java, javafx

Each section within the borderpane contains a layout such as a HBox. I wouldl like the borderpane to fit the scene and to be able to resize each section (such as the HBoxes) within the borderpane to preferred sizes. Thanks

[image: Here is what is currently looks like]

Comment: hi, if you intend to create a GUI using java fx i suggest to change to java fxml. Java fxml gives you the ability to use scene builder which is a tool for creating GUIs

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll learn some fxml. But is there no way to do this without?

Comment: And how would you do it with fxml?

Comment: Use an [AnchorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html) as the root.

Comment: If you want it to fit to parent (which ever your parent choose to be[anchor pane, tab pane, etc..]) right click on the borderpane and click fit to parent. Then click on the borderpane and go to layout (right hand side menu and click on the four boxes on the top to set the borderpane to be resizable for each side). When are activeted the boxes will become red